# Rewrite url with id and title (php)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How to rewrite url (what to do) so that instead:
http://www.example.com/article.php?id=123
it says:
http://www.example.com/articles/123/article_title_read_from_database
using php and mysql
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do SEO rewriting? That usually means that when someone types in http://www.example.com/articles/article_title it's redirected to http://www.example.com/article.php?id=article_title - this script then looks up article_title in the database to decide what content to display

Comment: Do you want to rewrite `/articles/article_title` internally to `/article.php?id=article_title` or do you want to redirect `/article.php?id=article_title` externally to `/articles/article_title`?

Comment: Second one, I guess. Slugs, is it? Using php mysql and whatever else it takes.

Answer (score 0):

When the example article.php well page is accessed with the GET of id=123, the php code to retrieve the number is

`$my_id = $_GET['id']`

, in this case, that would produce 123.

Then you can redirect the page using

```
header('Location: http://example.com/articles/$id/other stuff');
```

I'll leave the MySQL stuff for someone else, but a simple tutorial will give you alot of info on that.

Comment: Looks like a misunderstand. I need to know what to type in a .httaccess to replace something.php?id= with something/idnumber/article_title

Answer (score 0):

To process request and redirect to new url:

```
// get id of record from URL
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
// suppose connection to database is established already
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `title` FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = $id");
if (!$result) {
    // there is no such an article
    // you can redirect to some other page, or show some error message
} else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $title = $row['title'];
    $urlPart = generateURL($title);
    header('location:/articles/$id/$urlPart');
    exit;
}
```

you'll need `generateURL` function, that take string input and replace all unusable characters with `_`. (For example if you have title "What's going on?" it will replace `'`, `?` and whitespaces to something like "what_s_going_on"). You can use `str_replace` or `preg_replace` to achieve this.

If you want to generate new URL on multiple places, you can insert URL form of title directly into database as another column `title_url` and then just select it and use it instead of `title`:

```
SELECT `title_url` FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = $id
```

There is no way you can do this kind of rewriting in `.htaccess` as you can't connect to database server from within this file. (Or at least I don't know such a solution)